# Cannot understand difference between the two ip addresses in relation to hosting?

Tags: node.js, iis, networking, network-programming, windows-11

I have used [IIS](https://www.iis.net/) to host a nodejs API in windows 11(followed these blogs: [blog-1](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/iis-how-to-setup-a-web-site) and [blog-2](https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b)).

When following blog-1, setting the IP address to IPv6(i am not sure about this) makes the API available to all device.
Any other options choosen from the list of avail IP addresses leads to the API accessible only from the working pc where the API is hosted.

Why is this happening?

Also, when using the IPv6 address to reach the API, the url looks like this:
http://[5468:6483:7e05:6ea6:7c31:dd39:d7d2:f8b7] (Note: `this is a mock url, does not work`)

Here, what is the `[]` used for?

Note:

- I don't have much knowledge about this topic, if the question needs any improvement please suggest edits.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. what means about `IP addresses leads to the API accessible only from the working pc where the API is hosted`? I understand the meaning of `[]` is used to protect IPv6 address, because some urls have some other characters besides the ip address.

Comment: @samwu When I am not using the IPv6 address, the API cannot be accessed from other devices. Can u understand??

Comment: when then api cannot be accessed from other devices, did you get any error messages?

Comment: @samwu not reachable err.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.